# При передаче значений через curl POST происходит автозамена + на " "

Tags: php, post, curl

При передаче параметров в $postfields в запросе который приходит на URL символ + заменен на ' '

```
if ($_POST) {
    $data = array();
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (!next($_POST)){
        }
        else{
        $data[] = stripslashes($key) . "=" . stripslashes($value);
        }
    }
    $postfields = join("&", $data);
}

        $url = 'https://url/';
        $timeout = 30;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,$timeout);   // The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $server_output = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);
        if ($server_output['resultCode'] == 0){
            $link = $server_output['resultData']['paymentForm']['action'];
            header("Location: ".$link."");
        }
        else{
            echo $server_output['resultMsg'];
        }
        curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: К чему такие извращения? есть же [`http_build_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.http-build-query.php) специально для таких случаев.

Comment: @hindmost согласен и + превратит в `%21` но не точно, да и не суть, там надо будет еще `urlencode` вызвать скорее всего, хотя не точно, надо смотреть.

Comment: собственно если не важен `multipart/form-data` вместо `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` - то в CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS можно передавать сразу массив.